# Closing an application in full screen leaves a black box in Mission Control

Tags: macos, fullscreen

I have a MacBook Air with OS X EL Capitan 10.11.6, when I use an app like Safari or email and so on, in fullscreen mode the app work very well. But when I close the app and restart the mac I see this: [image]

or

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I read [this](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91861) and it seems to be a problem occurring when `CMD+Q` is brutally pushed to close a not Apple App.

Substantially, I suppose it should be a bug of the program that you are closing and so – maybe – you have to wait a bug fix update from the developer of the App in question.